# Dotnet core - Environment variable per application(process) on same server

Tags: iis, asp.net-core

We are using the following code:

```
if(env.IsDevelopment()) 
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

This works great when developing locally and in production, but we have a problem in our CI/QA environment, they are located on the same server.

We would like to be able to specify something like this, but how do we set the environment variable per application? If CI and QA had been on different servers, this would be easy to solve.

```
if(env.IsEnvironment("CI")) 
{
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}
```

We would also want to have specific appsettings.json for each environment like `appsettings.ci.json` and `appsettings.qa.json` and I know that this works out of the box with environment variables.

Im sure that it must be a way to specify environment variables per application(process), I just don't know how? :)

We are using IIS to host our application.

Comment: Environment variables are _per process_, which I presume is what you wanted anyway (CI and QA are the same application, but different processes). Your problem however is that both processes have the same parent process (IIS), and therefore inherit the same environment variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got help from @davidfowl in the dotnet core slack channel.

The solution is to add the following to `aspNetCore` section in your `web.config` file

```
<environmentVariables>
    <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
    <environmentVariable name="AnotherVariable" value="My Value" />
</environmentVariables>
```

So my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false">
    <environmentVariables>
        <environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="QA" />
        <environmentVariable name="AnotherVariable" value="My Value" />
    </environmentVariables>
</aspNetCore>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may override value in `env.EnvironmentName` as it has public setter and you may use only specific group of environment variables per application. Lets say there are 2 variables like `APP1_OWNENVIRONMENT = "QA"`, `APP2_OWNENVIRONMENT = "CI"` for app1 and app2 respectively.

1. When you add environment variable support by calling `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` method, it is possible to specify filter to ignore all variables without special prefix. For example

   ```
       // APP1_ is the prefix that environment variable names must start with.
       var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .AddCommandLine(args)
           .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "APP1_")
           .Build();

       env.EnvironmentName = config.GetValue<string>("OWNENVIRONMENT")};

       // here env.EnvironmentName has "QA" value so the appsettings.qa.json will be used 
       var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
           .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
           .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true);
   ```
2. Methods like `IsDevelopment()`, `IsStaging()` are just an [extension methods](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs) for  `IHostingEnvironment` that are wrappers over general `IsEnvironment` method:

   ```
   public static bool IsDevelopment(this IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
   {
      if (hostingEnvironment == null)
      {
          throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hostingEnvironment));
      }

      return hostingEnvironment.IsEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development);
   }
   ```

So you can create your own `IsQA()` extension method by analogy, or call directly `env.IsEnvironment("QA")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I managed to solve it with web.config with a little help from @davidfowl. See my answer.